# Set Basemap meridians or parallels labels within plot or change color of text

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I am making a map with Basemap in python and I'd like for the meridians/parallels to be either inside the plot or for the text (i.e. 0˚N) to be white. I want to do this so that I can set the figure against a black background but still read the axes.

This is what I have:

```
# plot lines of longitudes
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,1),labels=[1,1,1,1])

# plot latitudes
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180,1),labels=[1,0,0,1])
```

and in case it helps here's the basemap instance and packages used:

```
m = Basemap(resolution=None, # c, l, i, h, f or None
        projection='merc',
        llcrnrlon=33.795774, llcrnrlat=-6.182035, 
        urcrnrlon=34.6000037, urcrnrlat=6.236179,epsg=5520)  

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

But it sets the labels outside the map and they're black.

Answer (score 0):

To change the ticks or the text colour, you need to use the additional parameters to `drawmeridians`/`drawparallels`. `color` changes the tick colour, `textcolor` changes the text colour. You can change more properties of the text by passing in additional text kwargs ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawparallels)). I have also grabbed the figure object and changed the background colour to show it working when black. Note the additional args to `savefig` if you want to save the figure with a different background colour.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m = Basemap(resolution='h', # c, l, i, h, f or None
        projection='merc',
        llcrnrlon=33.795774, llcrnrlat=-6.182035, 
        urcrnrlon=34.6000037, urcrnrlat=6.236179,epsg=5520)  

m.drawcoastlines()

# plot lines of longitudes
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,1),labels=[1,1,1,1], color='white', textcolor='white')

# plot latitudes
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180,1),labels=[1,0,0,1], color='white', textcolor='white')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_facecolor('black')
fig.savefig("white ticks.png", facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

[image: White ticks and labels]